# A piece of clothes for cleaning something

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

A mop has a stick part.

I don't know the term for a piece of clothes without stick, for cleaning something held by hand.

What should I call a piece of towel or a similar thing that is used to clean floor/window/shoes?

In my language, there are two related terms: one is for wiping a quite dirty thing, the other is for wiping a rather clean thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for ***Cleaning cloth***:

> a cloth used for cleaning; specifically, a cotton fabric of coarse spongy texture.

[image].
from Amazon

Answer (score 4):

You could call it a ***rag*** if you're using an *old* piece of cloth (could also be an *old* towel):

> : A **rag** is a piece of old cloth which you can use to clean or wipe things.
>
> ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rag))